# Concatenate date in statement

Tags: vba, vb6

I need to concatenate this statement with a date variable

```
Dia = Date

"SELECT dia, amanha, tarde, noite FROM TB_teste where dia = " & dia & ", cnnMysql, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly"
```

This Statement is used on mysql database

```
 select * from tb_teste where dia like '2016-01-08'
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: This seems to be OK. Do you get an error message or just don't get the desired results or...?

Comment: did you try: `Dia = "#" & Date & "#"` , or `Dia = CLng(Date)` .

Comment: is this sql going against Access?

Comment: VBA and your database could be using different date formats.  If you wanted to pass a VBA date to SQL Server, for example, you should use the [FORMAT function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx) like so:  Dia = Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD").  Don't forget your SQL statement would want the date delimited with single quotes.

Comment: I don't think the last part should be in quotes; `" & dia , cnnMysql, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly`

Comment: with formatting the line should be `"SELECT dia, amanha, tarde, noite FROM TB_teste where dia = '" & dia & "'", cnnMysql, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly`

Answer (score 2):

*Just don't do it.*

Ignoring the vulnerability of dynamically generated SQL to SQL Injection attacks (intentional and inadvertant) you also run into these Provider-specific value literal format issues.  Just use a parameter query instead.

```
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
With RS
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .LockType = adLockReadOnly
End With
With New ADODB.Command
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = "SELECT dia, amanha, tarde, noite FROM TB_teste " _
                 & "where dia = ?"
    .Name = "TestesQuery"
    .ActiveConnection = cnnMysql
    cnnMysql.TestesQuery Date, RS
End With
```

Your named `TestesQuery` becomes an extended property of the Connection object, and can be executed as such.  Row-returning queries invoked in this manner expect the last argument to be a Recordset set up to receive the rowset.  The other arguments are your anonymous query parameters, processed in order of definition in the SQL string.

You can execute stored procedures by name in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Format()` function to convert your date in a string in the format you want.

```
stringDate = Format(Dia, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
```

You can then concatenate the `stringDate` where you need